# CS50 DNA - it works for small.csv but not for large

Tags: python, cs50

[https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/6/dna/#:~:text=python%20dna.py%20databases/large.csv%20sequences/5.txt](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/6/dna/#:%7E:text=python%20dna.py%20databases/large.csv%20sequences/5.txt)

I'm trying to solve this problem from CS50 but it just works for the small database, when I try it for the large one the program overcounts.

```
import csv

if len(argv) != 3:
    print("DIGITA DIREITO, IMBECIL")
    exit()

with open(argv[1], "r") as source:

    reader = list(csv.reader(source))
    reader[0].remove("name")

    i = reader[0]

with open(argv[2], "r") as sequence:

    seq = sequence.read()

values = []

for j in range(len(i)):

    value = 0
    counter = 0
    pos = 0
    prevpos = 0

    while pos < len(seq):

        pos = seq.find(i[j], pos)

        if pos == -1:
            counter = 0
            break

        elif (pos != 1):
            counter += 1
            prevpos = pos
            pos += len(i[j])
            if value < counter:
                value = counter


    values.append(value)
for row in range(len(reader)):
        print(reader[row])
print(values)

values = list(map(str, values))

search = list(reader)
search.pop(0)

for result in search:
    if result[1:] == values:
        print(f"{result[0]}")
        break

    elif result == search[-1]:
        print("No match")
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "overcounts" - what is the expected output and what do you actually get?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just counting the STRs repetitions in the sequence, not the *maximum consecutive STR repetitions*. This is what the problem asks